# How to add links to websites on a resume

Tags: websites

I have user accounts on stackoverflow, project euler, and git hub. How would I add these to a resume as proof that I can program and know what I say I do?

Comment: Unless you're using multiple accounts, you haven't actually posted anything at all on SO. That's not evidence of very much at all :-)

Comment: I am only in my second year of my BS in Comp Sci but like to be prepared! That will change.

Comment: We not use the Stackoverflow resume feature. You can link your github projects directly and add a link to euler. As an example mine is here: https://careers.stackoverflow.com/lokiastari

Comment: That is definitely what I will do. I obviously need to accomplish things first but that is a great example thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a section to your resume:

> **My online programming presence**
>
> Stackoverflow:  https://stackoverflow.com/users/5505382/k-schmidt
>
> Github:
>
> Project Euler:

You want to have the URLs spelled out as text so that if a potential employer strips your electronic copy to unformatted text they still have the addresses available.  Your electronic copy should have the URLs clickable as well.

Optionally put a sentence or two of text about what the sites are.  A technical manager probably won't need an explanation of why the sites matter, but if HR prescreens resumes, knowing that they're something that should be relevant might help.

However unless you have something substantial at the accounts I wouldn't bother.  For here, probably at least several dozen good questions/answers; your current "I have an account" presence level on stackexchange doesn't get you anything.  At Github, something more substantial than just school assignments.  I'm not familiar enough with Project Euler to suggest any particular threshold.

Comment: Thanks a lot that makes sense and will be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do would be the following:

- Create a holding/intro page for my examples rather than a number of links in the resume/CV.  This could have a mini bio and links to LinkedIn etc in case someone finds you via Google rather than your CV.
- Use a url shortening service to ensure it's easy to type if the reader has to enter it from a paper copy
- Host the page in somewhere you can add Google Analytics (or in WordPress etc), so you can see where viewers are coming from/what they are interested in.

You can then see if it's getting you anywhere and update areas where you are getting interest (without having to send updated CVs).  With GA you can still track if they step off into GitHub etc